# How can I set, reset or over-write a variable in Azure Pipelines at runtime in Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, azure-pipelines

Setting up a variable at runtime in Azure Pipelines does not work in neither Poweshell 1.0 nor 2.0

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
```

Does not set any value which I could refer in another step or a pipeline, if I execute the following:

```
Write-Host "The value is: $env:sauce"    # line 10
Write-Host "The value is: $(sauce)"      # line 11
```

The output for line 10 is

```
The value is:
```

And an error on line 11:

```
sauce : The term 'sauce' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\AzurePipelines\Agent\work\_temp\cf78918a-9bc2-4874-ad26-fbc3c5165627.ps1:11
```

I tried several other ways, even I created a variable and a variable group, tried to over-write the values, nothing worked. even if I did set cehcked the box "settable at queue time" box.

Comment: Do you set and print in one step?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat yes, of course, I did try setting the value and fetching it in many different ways but nothing that worked. In order to avoid unnecessary length of the question, I didn't add each and every detail.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat the above is working for some, I beleive, there are blogs, help and even in other Stackoverflow questions people used the same example, for some strange reasons, it doesn' work for me.

Comment: I think if you set this way and print it wont work, it should set variable for next step

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat thatäs the catch. I added anoher powershell step and it did work on that step - Thanks!. However, I am still unable to rest the value of an already existing variable in the pipeline.

Comment: What do you mean? I will write comment as answer for now

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I meant if I create a variable in the pipeline using the variablesGroup, can I reset the value of that variable at runtime?

Comment: You should, because for instance I am rewriting release name that way.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat just tested again, didn't work. I created a variable "DeploymentEnvironmentName"=ABCDEF. Chnaged the value in the PS to "UAT". Recalled it in another PS script/step. "$env:DeploymentEnvironment" gives UAT in a powershell script but in any other step, like MSBUILD step when I call it as $(DeploymentEnvironment), it gives ABCDEF not UAT

Comment: Did you use Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DeploymentEnvironmentName]UAT" ?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat yes, exactly like that^^

Comment: Are they within same phase?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat yes they are in the same phase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205118/discussion-between-wafers-and-volodymyr-bilyachat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting variable via

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
```

Will work after task is complete, Pipeline will read console and set variable, so you can use it in any other step.

So if you want to print you must have step one where you set it and other step where you use it.